# Categories/subcategories in rails as drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, categories

Hi I'm a bit of ROR noob. Wondering if anyone can help me implement a drop down menu that shows categories and their subcategories?

What sort of code will get me started?

I've already entered the data for the categories, I'm just not sure where to put the code to make them appear as a friendly drop down menu with their subcategories as a branch of each category.

Any help would be great.

EDIT this is what code I have for the drop down:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Categories
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pop Culture</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tazos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Woolworths Collectibles</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

and I would like to add an on-hover or on-click action that shows the sub-categories of the categories in the list.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your current code. Are you trying to show `subcategories` based on the selected `category`?

Comment: please see edit

Comment: It seems that is a different question. I would recommend podsting a new question (referencing this one). You will get more people to look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to add some interactivity to the view layer of your application. The type of code that will get you started with this feature is Javascript. The `app/assets/javascripts` directory of your project is where you put this code. By default, while you are building your application in a development environment, Ruby on Rails will reload any changes you make to files inside this directory each time you refresh the view in your browser.

The Rails Guides have excellent documentation on the manner in which Rails handles your static assets such as javascript, and your CSS files.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

There are an amazing amount of free resources available with a little googling, which show you the basics of javascript, and how to make dropdown menus.

There is also a powerful javascript library called JQuery that can make what you are looking to do even more straightforward.

[This walkthrough seems very similar to what you are trying to achieve. You can customize it to fit your needs.](http://callmenick.com/post/slide-down-menu-with-jquery-and-css)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! This will be a great help. It looks like what I need.

Comment: I am glad I could help. :)

Comment: please see edit. i have a bootstrap front page that i'd like to add the above to, but I'm not sure how to get the thing to work even after looking at the link you posted...